# Is the Netbeans output stored in a file?

Tags: java, netbeans

I just run a massive simulation in NetBeans and the computer crashed before I could copy the output from the output window to a file.

Does anybody know if this output has been stored in any temporary file, or if it is lost forever?

And where could it be stored?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: If you had a logger configured, you could be saved. But if it was only on terminal you have a hard luck

Comment: unfortunately no logger was used. Just the normal System.out.println(). Thanx anyway

Comment: Just to make the post complete, how would you recover the output if Logger was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean System.out?

Do smth like this:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

Comment: Yes I get my output with System.out. I normally copy/paste them from the output window of netbeans to an excel sheet for further processing. I know how to write to files with Java. My question is if the output window contents are stored to a temporary file by netbeans.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not stored...

Comment: If you 'd have used the logger, would have logged all your expectations, logger is available for netbeans ,try to follow it